# Strange update: "Safe and Easy Web Browser from Mozilla firefox"

Tags: firefox, update-manager

Following one or two updates I have now Mozilla Firefox version 25.0.1 installed on Ubuntu, which works fine.

Today I noticed that the Ubuntu Update Manager is suggesting me to install a strange "Safe and Easy Web Browser from Mozilla firefox" (30.6 Mb) update, along with a transitional package, and English, Hungarian language packs, which is strange, because I have already both English and Hungarian language packs for Firefox 25.0.1 installed.

As I know Firefox 25.0.1 is the currently latest version, and Firefox updates comes always with a new identifying sub-number (not named), without language packs.

Has anyone received such a huge update with that name? What is this? A new, second browser from Firefox, a security update (too large for that, and why sent with language packs), or was it sent by mistake? Do I need it at all?

Comment: Firefox 26 is the latest version.

Comment: Thanx Falconer! You are right. Firefox 26 was released on 12. dec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run 12.04 as well and Firefox is labelled as "Safe and Easy Web Browser from Mozilla firefox" in Update Manager
It should be safe to update. I am running v 26.0
The language pack update is expected with a new version/update

Comment: Problem solved, thanx user224859